# When to use individual optimizers in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

The example given [here](https://github.com/spro/practical-pytorch/blob/master/seq2seq-translation/seq2seq-translation.ipynb) uses two optimizers for `encoder` and `decoder` individually. Why? And when to do like that?

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you consider to mark as accepted so that the question stays no longer unanswered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have multiple networks (in the sense of multiple objects that inherit from `nn.Module`), you have to do this for a simple reason: When construction a `torch.nn.optim.Optimizer` object, it takes the parameters which should be optimized as an argument. In your case:

```py
encoder_optimizer = optim.Adam(encoder.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
decoder_optimizer = optim.Adam(decoder.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
```

This also gives you the freedom to vary parameters as the learning rate independently. If you don't need that, you could create a new class inheriting from `nn.Module` and containing both networks, encoder and decoder or create a set of parameters to give to the optimizer as explained [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-train-several-network-at-the-same-time/4920/4?u=mclawrence):

```
nets = [encoder, decoder]
parameters = set()
for net in nets:
    parameters |= set(net.parameters())
```

where `|` is the union operator for sets in this context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then is that mean if we have only the `encoder` and `decoder` class which inherits from `nn.Module`, simple pipelining the hiddens of the encoder to the decoder (e.g. `enc_out, enc_hidden = encoder(x); dec_out = decoder(y, enc_hidden)`) and using only one `optimizer` will not work in this situation?

Comment: @displayname I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Can you elaborate in your question

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I think the two ways you mentioned are standard ways to do this.

Comment: @displayname: I meant, what do you mean by this: "`enc_out, enc_hidden = encoder(x); dec_out = decoder(y, enc_hidden`". Or did the two ways already helped you?